# Changing one scale widget will change the secone one

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, slider, scale

I have two scale widgets in my code that are supposed to display values from a list. I want to be able to set individual values for both sliders. For example, for file 1 "2.4" and for file 2 "5.025". But currently I can only update the second (lower) slider without it triggering the first (upper) one. If I use the upper one, the value of the second one is also changed.

I'm stuck implementing the lambda function, so it would be create if some could give me a hint.
Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk


class File_Selection():
    def __init__(self, frame, text):

        self.frame = frame
        self.text = text

        self.label_file = tk.Label(self.frame, text=text)
        self.label_file.pack(side="left", anchor="s")

        self.label_test = tk.Label(self.frame, text="| Select value: ")
        self.label_test.pack(side="left", anchor="s")

        self.scale = tk.Scale(self.frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, from_=0)
        self.scale.pack(side="left", anchor="s")

class View:

    def __init__(self, view):

        self.view = view

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.view)
        self.frame.pack()
    
        self.frame_row1 = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame_row1.pack(side="top")

        self.frame_row2 = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame_row2.pack(side="top")

        self.file_one = File_Selection(self.frame_row1, "File 1")
        self.file_two = File_Selection(self.frame_row2, "File 2")


class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root)

        self.values = [1.01,2.4,3.6,4.89,5.025,6.547]

        self.view.file_one.scale.bind('<Enter>', self.update_scale)
        self.view.file_two.scale.bind('<Enter>', self.update_scale)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_scale(self, event):
        self.active_scales = [self.view.file_one.scale, self.view.file_two.scale]

        for scale in self.active_scales:
            scale.config(from_=min(self.values), to=max(self.values), resolution=0.001, command=lambda value=scale: self.set_scale(value, scale))
            
    def set_scale(self, value, scale):
        self.newvalue = min(self.values, key=lambda x: abs(x-float(value)))
        scale.set(self.newvalue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Comment: It looks like you set ```active_scales``` once and never change it. If active scales is always both scales, then the expected behavior is for both scales to update.

Comment: Is there a reason why you ```bind``` both scales to update there values when the mouse ```Enter```'s either widgets. If not, just remove that binding and the ```update_scale``` function. Otherwise, it would help to know the intention of the binding.

Comment: At the end, I will load to files in my application which has the values for the scale stored. In the example the list "self.values" should represent this. My intention was to update the possible scale values, that the user can select only the values which are stored in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have both scales set to `active_scales`. You can take advantage of the `event` and do away with `active_scales`.

You can get the `widget` associated with an `event` with `event.widget`. So, you can change the `update_scales` function from

```
def update_scale(self, event):
    self.active_scales = [self.view.file_one.scale, self.view.file_two.scale]
        for scale in self.active_scales:
            scale.config(from_=min(self.values), to=max(self.values), resolution=0.001, command=lambda value=scale: self.set_scale(value, scale))
```

to

```
def update_scale(self, event):
    event.widget.config(from_=min(self.values), to=max(self.values), resolution=0.001, command=lambda value=event.widget: self.set_scale(value, event.widget))
```

Additionally, since `self.values` don't appear to change, it does not seem necessary to `config` each scale to change its bounds and resolution on each `event`. You can instead pull that out of the event and make you `Controller` class as follows.

```
class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root)

        self.values = [1.01,2.4,3.6,4.89,5.025,6.547]

        self.view.file_one.scale.bind('<Enter>', self.update_scale)
        self.view.file_two.scale.bind('<Enter>', self.update_scale)
        self.view.file_one.scale.config(from_=min(self.values), to=max(self.values), resolution=0.001)
        self.view.file_two.scale.config(from_=min(self.values), to=max(self.values), resolution=0.001)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_scale(self, event):
        event.widget.config(command=lambda value=event.widget: self.set_scale(value, event.widget))
       
    def set_scale(self, value, scale):
        self.newvalue = min(self.values, key=lambda x: abs(x-float(value)))
        scale.set(self.newvalue)
```

Comment: Thanks! Using "event.widget" did the magic.